# Правильно ли будет не создавать поле уникальных значений в таблице SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Правильно ли будет не создавать поле уникальных значений в таблице SQL?
Нормально ли будет работать нижеприведенная таблица?
Реляционная бд.

Вот:

```
CREATE TABLE `dev_users` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `part_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','2','3','0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `order` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`part_id`,`order`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `part_id` (`part_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `part_id` FOREIGN KEY (`part_id`) REFERENCES `part_develop` (`part_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: если оно вам не нужно почему бы и нет

Comment: @Naumov Боюсь, не будет ли это работать медленнее или с глюками. Спасибо.

Comment: Всё зависит от архитектуры если вам нужна некая таблица для жоинта, и некий индетификатор никогда не будет использоваться, то зачем оно нужно.

Comment: @Naumov Большое прибольшое, спасибо.

Comment: Вы бы написали за что поля отвечают, особенно order. вопрос делать так или нет заключается исключительно в природе данных. И еще важно будет ли необходимость из других таблиц ссылаться на данную. ссылка по 3м полям тяжела в поддержке. уникальность с order странно немного выглядит. обычно связи двух таблиц через данную сами по себе уникальны, а судя по тому что тут две записи из двух таблиц могут быть связаны друг с другом одновременно с разными order ...

Comment: @Mike `order` - порядок от 1 до ..... У каждого `user_id`,`part_id` - свой порядок. Это значит что, две записи с одинакомым `user_id` ,`part_id`  и порядком `order` , существовать не должны.

Comment: @gilo1212 Но две записи с одинаковыми user_id и part_id но разными order могут быть ... тогда ключ правильный. Будем считать, что фразу "_у каждого user_id, part_id_", я неверно понял, думая что order у них только один ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ короткий: вполне нормально. Более того, именно так и нужно делать в вашем случае.

Создавать уникальное поле, которое никогда и никем не будет использоваться будет бОльшей ошибкой.